# Serialization Exception in Spring-kafka Consumer Exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, deserialization, spring-kafka, json-deserialization

When sending any message to my SpringBoot Kafka application, I am facing the Serialization Exception, here is the log.

```
2021-02-24 01:28:21.280  INFO 19249 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.6.0
2021-02-24 01:28:21.281  INFO 19249 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
2021-02-24 01:28:21.281  INFO 19249 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1614110301280
2021-02-24 01:28:21.294  INFO 19249 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: paGjVV-5RVyOatWyXOzBrQ
2021-02-24 01:28:21.365  INFO 19249 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.h.a.m.service.KafkaConsumer            : #### -> Consumed message -> "22:26 Hello World!!"
2021-02-24 01:28:21.400 ERROR 19249 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:145) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:113) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1427) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1124) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition myTopic-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[34, 50, 50, 58, 50, 54, 32, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 33, 32, 32, 74, 97, 105, 32, 83, 104, 114, 105, 32, 82, 97, 109, 33, 33, 32, 66, 97, 114, 97, 109, 98, 97, 97, 114, 32, 74, 97, 105, 32, 72, 111, 33, 33, 34]] from topic [myTopic]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.hcl.anusheel.messagestream.request.dto.EntryObject` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('22:26 Hello World!!')
 at [Source: (byte[])""22:26 Hello World!!""; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1455) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1081) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1408) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:176) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2079) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1555) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:517) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1365) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:130) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1596) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1432) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:684) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:635) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1308) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1271) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1162) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1075) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-02-24 01:28:21.412 ERROR 19249 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception
```

How to fix this?

Here is the EntryObject.java class, this is part of the incoming request object which would be serialized and fed to the Kafka topic and the same should be retrieved from the Kafka Consumer for further processing.

```
public class EntryObject {
    @NonNull
    private String tradeId;
    @NonNull
    private int version;
    @NonNull
    private String counterPartyId;
    @NonNull
    private String bookId;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") 
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate maturityDate;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") 
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate createdDate;
    private char expired;
    
    public String getTradeId() {
        return tradeId;
    }
    public void setTradeId(String tradeId) {
        this.tradeId = tradeId;
    }
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public String getCounterPartyId() {
        return counterPartyId;
    }
    public void setCounterPartyId(String counterPartyId) {
        this.counterPartyId = counterPartyId;
    }
    public String getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }
    public void setBookId(String bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }
    public LocalDate getMaturityDate() {
        return maturityDate;
    }
    public void setMaturityDate(LocalDate maturityDate) {
        this.maturityDate = maturityDate;
    }
    public LocalDate getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(LocalDate createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    public char getExpired() {
        return expired;
    }
    public void setExpired(char expired) {
        this.expired = expired;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EntryObject [tradeId=" + tradeId + ", version=" + version + ", counterPartyId=" + counterPartyId
                + ", bookId=" + bookId + ", maturityDate=" + maturityDate + ", createdDate=" + createdDate
                + ", expired=" + expired + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is my KafkaConsumerConfig.java class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(String groupId) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(groupId));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory("foo");
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> barKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory("bar");
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> headersKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory("headers");
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> partitionsKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory("partitions");
    }

    
    public ConsumerFactory<String, EntryObject> entryObjectConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "entryObject");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(EntryObject.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, EntryObject> entryObjectKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, EntryObject> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(entryObjectConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

and here is my KafkaConsumer.java class

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
    
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);
    
    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "foo", containerFactory = "fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(String message) throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", message));
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", containerFactory = "entryObjectKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(EntryObject entryObject) throws IOException {
        logger.info("received entryObject = '{}'", entryObject.toString());
    }
}
```

How to fix this exception? And have a smoothly running application.

Comment: Looks like the data in topic is not in JSON format, i believe this is not valid JSON `22:26 Hello World!!`

Comment: The message value is the JSON string `"22:26 Hello World!!"`, but JsonDeserializer expects to read a JSON object.

Comment: Its a string, I have defined two KafkaListeners in the consumer class, they handler both the String and EntryObject, for which there should be JSON object. Should I not be providing 2 or more KafkaListeners in the same class? I have seen others do that. Please kindly elaborate further on how should I come out of this exception.

Comment: @Chin Huang How to make the application invoke the correct deserializer? When the EntryObject is coming it should be invoking the JSON object deserializer and when the JSON string is there then it should be invoking the correct String deserializer as defined in the KafkaConsumerConfig class.

Comment: If you don't want to invoke the EntryObject deserializer, then delete the method annotated with `@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", containerFactory = "entryObjectKafkaListenerContainerFactory")`

Comment: The behavior I want is this if I send the String to the application then it should consume that and be deserialized with a String deserializer, and when I send a JSON for a request object then that particular request object deserializer should kick in.

I mean people have that behavior in their application, Why can't I do it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.hcl.anusheel.messagestream.request.dto.EntryObject` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('22:26 Hello World!!')

The Json is a JSON encoded string `"..."`.

Jackson is trying to find a constructor for entry object that looks like this...

```
public EntryObject(String data) { ... }
```

and there is no such CTOR.

Comment: But I have two functions in my KafkaConsumer class Gary, how to specify that the one with the String deserializer be invoked when the incoming object is of type String and  the EntryObject deserializer be invoked when the incoming object is of EntryObject. Please elaborate more on this also please tell what should be done to get rid of exceptions  in desererialization  process.

Comment: Actually the EntryObject deserializer should not at all be called!! If that is getting called then it is not what I had inteded, so what should I do that the correct deserializer is called.

Comment: Your `entryObjectConsumerFactory` is configured to use a `JsonDeserializer` to use the  the String to create an `EntryObject` - it requires the proper constructor on `EntryObject` to do that. Use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` to handle deserialization exceptions which will be sent directly to the error handler. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer